# Confused about building process for .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have very simple test application:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Management.Automation;

namespace CoreTest
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Waiting...");
            Console.ReadKey();
            using (var ps = PowerShell.Create())
            {
                ps.Commands.AddCommand("Get-Host");
                var result = ps.Invoke();
                Console.WriteLine(result.FirstOrDefault()?.Members?["Name"]?.Value);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Waiting...");
        }
    }
}
```

All it does is shows host name using powershell, and it mostly works.

Building part, however, is extremely confusing.

1. If I just build it and copy bin folder to Linux host, it doesn't work, saying that it can't find some package, which is expected.
2. If I publish and copy resulting folder without changing anything in Visual Studio it works, but resulting folder is 130MB, which suggests that something is wrong.
   Examining publish folder reveals that most of it is `runtimes` folder, with copies of dlls I use(`System.Management.Automation.dll`,`Microsoft.PowerShell.SDK.dll` etc) in folders for different platform targets(`win10-x64`,`linux-x64` etc).
   Documentation suggests that this (framework-dependent deployment) is the way to deploy smaller sized, .net core installation requiring applications, yet as you can see folder size for something that simple is absolutely suboptimal.
3. If I start targeting specific platforms(which is the how documentation suggests to deploy bigger, .net core installation independent applications, "Framework-dependent deployment") by adding `RuntimeIdentifiers` to the `.csproj` file, size does get a bit smaller(about 70MB), yet result still refuses to work on my testing ubuntu machine:
   [image: run error]

What am I missing?

All I want is reasonably sized folder with dll that is guaranteed to run on target machine - say, Ubuntu one.

Comment: You should not "build it" for distributing, instead you should publish. Run `dotnet publish`

Comment: Also you have to variant of publishing: framework-agnostic (all needed assemblies are included) and framework-dependant (only your assemblies are included, and it's expected to find the same framework on target machine)

Comment: So at the end you actually published your app as Framework-dependent but I guess the target machine has no the same dotnet installed as the machine where you built the app.